# Launch IPA file after installed on device

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I managed to install applications in the IPA format on (non jailbroken) iOS devices from my terminal using libimobiledevice. Unfortunately this only takes me halfway. Now I need to start the newly installed application automatically as a part of our nightly build job for testing purposes.

All information is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using another utility (which depends on libimobiledevice):

[Crackleware iDevice App Runner (GitHub)](https://github.com/crackleware/idevice-app-runner)

Answer (score 5):

I suggest use `idevicedebug` from the `libimobiledevice` library. https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice.

Command goes like: `idevicedebug run [APP_ID]`. Usually, you would have to run `ideviceinstaller -l` first to get the APP_ID value before running `idevicedebug`.

This worked for me, hope it does with you too.